# UART sending gaps

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, uart

I am sending data via a 16550a UART that has a 16 byte FIFO. When I send 26 bytes, I see 16 bytes transmitted at correct baud rate. Then a 19 ms pause and then 12 bytes.

I am not using interrupts.

I am not sure where to start debugging this. I send from a kernel module and setup terminal with these flags:

```
c_cflag is CLOCAL CREAD CS8 B38400 HUPCL
```

other flags are 0. I use `driver->ops->write()` to send one char at a time.

Running Linux kernel v5.10 on an embedded SoC with serial8250 driver.

Comment: The baudrate only applies to the bits of the UART frame. Each frame encompasses only one character, and not a datagram. It's an asynchronous link, so a gap between char/frames is allowed, and should not matter to the receiver (unless you're using a special protocol such as Modbus).

Comment: If you have the source code for a device driver and can modify it, you should review its design and modify it. There's probably nothing the application can do, and even if it could do something, it would probably replace some behavior in the device driver.

Comment: Either use a separate micro-controller or switch to RTOS. There is no issue in what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up changing the uart fifo size from 16 bytes to 32. and the 8250 driver to 32 from 16bytes. it now works for what i need. thanks

Comment: Which is not correct.

Comment: It's better to close the question in this case.
Also, it would be much appreciated if you specify the issue and what solved in the answer

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add @USER to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)